# SpringBoot Cache: specific configuration for each cache

Tags: spring-boot, caffeine-cache

I am experimenting [Cache](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.6/reference/html/io.html#io.caching) in Spring Boot. At moment, I am using Caffeine implementation. From what I've read from the documentation, I've configured the caches in YAML as follows:

```yaml
spring:
  cache:
    cache-names:
      - skills
      - profile-level-type
    caffeine:
      spec: maximumSize=50,expireAfterAccess=60s
```

Where `skills` and `profile-level-type` correspond to different `@Service`s. It is working. However I would like something that more flexible. Apparently, I cannot make a configuration to a specific cache. I was thinking something about this:

```yaml
spring:
  cache:
    caffeine:
      skills: maximumSize=50,expireAfterAccess=60s
      profile-level-type: maximumSize=5,expireAfterAccess=3600s
```

Is it possible? If not with Caffeine at least with another cache provider (JCache, EhCache, etc.)?

Comment: There is an alternative provider, [coffee-boots](https://github.com/stepio/coffee-boots), to help with that. This youtuber's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ze3qFp5pGeA&t=270s) shows native example where it works out of the box. So maybe it is supported natively in more recent versions (not a spring user).

Comment: I switched from Caffeine to EhCache to take advantege that I am using JPA / Hibernate cache. Its configuration allows a grained fine config that I was looking for.

Comment: I believe JPA/Hibernate use JCache, so that works in Caffeine if you add the extension. We probably need to add a few samples for Spring & JPA, I just haven't used them since 1.x of each.